# Why Havel-Hakimi theorem required that the degree sequence (that will be checked whether its a graph or not) to be in non-increasing order?

Tags: graph-theory

I was an undergraduate of mathematics department.

What I wonder is when i checking the following sequence, 6,5,5,4,3,3,2,2,2 using these theorems, like a method in Pearls in Graph Theory by Hartsfield-Ringel, such as

1) 6 5 5 4 3 3 2 2 2

2)  4 4 3 2 2 1 2 2

3)  4 4 3 2 2 2 2 1

4)    3 2 1 1 2 2 1

5)    3 2 2 2 1 1 1

6)      1 1 1 1 1 1

In the 5th steps i  have ordering the sequence in accordance with the theorem asked. In the end we know that 6,5,5,4,3,3,2,2,2 is a graphic. 
In step 5 then I ordering the sequence which represent the exchange of some edge, and in the end found a graph with the degree sequence 1,1,1,1,1
[illustration of graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug7Vl.jpg)

Then I compare with without ordering in 4th step, like

4) 3 2 1 1 2 2 1

5)   1 0 0 2 2 1

which yields
[graph in 5th step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdNl0.jpg)

which 1,0,0,2,2,1 is a graphic.

It seems that without us ordering these numbers, the  result still permit us to conclude that the degree sequence at the beginning is a graph.
Am I wrong? Is the theorem only guarantees when the degree  sequence is  non-increasing?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't bother reordering and you end up with a graphic sequence, you can still conclude the original sequence was graphic. However you may incorrectly conclude that the original sequence was not graphic. For example,

1) 2 2 2 2

2) 1 1 2

3) 0 2

Sequence 3 is not graphic, but sequence 1 is. The reason the algorithm requires reordering is that it ensures the final sequence is graphic if and only if the original one was.